# Set dropdown selected value in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using dropdown to show some values from db. I am binding the values in to the model by using the keyvaluepair as below

```
recurringPayment.CardType = paymentType.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.PaymentTypeId, x.Name)).ToList();
```

And in view:-

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.CardType, "Key", "Value"), "Click to Select", new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "cardTypeId", ng_required = "cardTypeRequired" })
```

My model is:

```
public class paymentModel
 {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> CardType { get; set; }
 }
```

in this dropdown the value from the db which is binded should be a selected one, but in my dropdown there is click to select is showing now, any ideas to implement this?

Comment: You need to set the value of recurringPayment.Id which one you would like to get selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this part, here :

```
new SelectList(Model.CardType, "Key", "Value")
```

you should simply chose the initial value

```
new SelectList(Model.CardType, "Key", "Value", selectedObject)
```

Comment: what is that selectedObject here?

Comment: No problem @Ranjith !